# CSRF issue on embedded form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, protect-from-forgery

I have a Wordpress site that embeds some elements of a Ruby on Rails site (which is our Members Area and is located on a subdomain). The elements include a login form. When people use it, Rails returns an error due to invalid CSRF token. Do I have to disable CSRF for the login action? What are my options? If the answer is to disable it, then is there a painless way to do so for Devise?

Comment: How do you embed the login form? Does it include hidden field with authenticity_token?

Comment: Even if you disable the csrf check for login, any other action will still not work in the Rails app I guess, so you'd be better off if you found the root cause of why it fails, because it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Do not disable the CSRF token for security purposes. Instead, look through the code and identify where the CSRF token is originating from, usually the DB, and then you can create a variable with that token value and echo it into an  field within the form in question with the specific CSRF token parameter that PHP is expecting.